# Why is Bundler version lookup selecting pre-release version here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, sass-rails

We have a gem which as development dependencies relies on `sass-rails` (specifically in version 5.0.4) which in turn depends on `railties >4.0.0` and `<5.0`.

Now we don't check our Gemfile.lock into the repo to keep it as flexible as possible (it's our 'universal' gem after all), and during the travis build, installing `sass-rails` resolves its dependency `railties` to version `5.0.0.beta1`, which I'd say intuitively isn't `<5.0` and now causes problems when running the tests on `ruby < 2.2.2` (due to `rack`).

Now, am I misunderstanding something or is this a bug, that bundler installs `5.0.0.beta1` for `<5.0`?

Comment: Why exactly don't you check in `Gemfile.lock`? AFAIK it's a bad practice

Comment: We don't check it in, since it's a gem anyway and the Gemfile.lock is of no consequence to the version lookup when using the gem in another project. By not checking it in, we are making sure, travis always uses the most recent version of every gem in the gemspec.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I missed it's a gem in the first read. Then it makes sense, since you can also specify versions in `gemspec` if needed.

Comment: What kind of flexibility does not checking in your `Gemfile.lock` give you? A gem's `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` only describe development dependencies. People who use your gem will only be restrained by the runtime dependencies in your `gemspec`.

Comment: @Raffael actually, the gemspec describes the development dependencies, too. With railties locked within Gemfile.lock our CI tests would have run and only subsequently caused other projects to fail that included this gem and would therefore include the latest version of railties as a dependency (since they don't follow Gemfile.lock). So, not putting in a Gemfile.lock makes it easy to catch these things during CI.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug but expected behaviour. Prerelease versions are expected to be released before the actual release, hence they are considered smaller.

See  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Version.html  for more detail.

You can add a **runtime** dependency to `railties '~> 4.0'` to your **gemspec** to solve this problem.

Comment: I was somehow under the assumption that prerelease versions wouldn't be selected at all, unless specifically told so by virtue of exact version number or a --pre modifier on the cmd line.